# Laptop speakers make noise when audio jack is plugged in

Tags: 14.04, sound, noise, audio-jack

I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad y410p with Ubuntu 14.04, and when I plug in headphones to my computer, the laptop speakers emit a loud, high pitched hum.

I've fixed the issue and just made this thread to answer it for others.

Comment: Any idea what caused this? When I used my laptop earlier today, I don't remember this sound. Then again, maybe I was using different headphones, I don't remember. Right before trying the headphones tonight, I uninstalled pulseaudio, but no idea if that's related to this problem.

Comment: @PJBrunet sorry I have no idea what caused the problem, it just started happening to me suddenly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution to this is to disable Auto-Mute Mode in alsamixer. Detailed instructions below.

Open up terminal and start alsamixer:

```
alsamixer
```

You should see a handful of tall columns with labels underneath, something like: Master, Headphone, Speaker, PCM, Mic, Mic Boost, S/PDIF, S/PDIF Default PC, Beep, Auto-Mute Mode, Internal Mic Boost

If you don't see these categories (specifically, if you don't see an "Auto-Mute Mode"), then try selecting a different sound card with F6. In my case I had to select HDA Intel PCH.

Notice "Enabled" above Auto-Mute Mode. Navigate to that item with the left/right arrow keys, and set it to Disabled with the up/down arrow keys. This should solve your problem, and you can exit alsamixer with Esc or by closing the terminal window.

Comment: I used this solution on Debian Jessie and it works.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 / Lenovo Y410p.

Comment: I guess this was specific to this model laptop? aparently everyone in this thread including me owns one. It worked great.

Comment: Debian 8 Jessie (Bunsen Labs) Lenovo Ideapad Y400 here. I'm not sure how this problem started.

Comment: still works on 17.10!

Comment: Thanks. This worked on Archlinux installed on Lenovo Ideapad 700. Interestingly, I had to *enable* Auto-Mute rather than disabling it!