# Pop, crack and background noise when I plug a jack (Ubuntu 14.04.3)

Tags: sound, audio-jack, noise, hda-intel

I have a [Dell inspiron 7746](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-17-7746-laptop/pd) ([Specs](http://pasted.co/54c47dbb)) series running Ubuntu 14.04.3 When I plug a headphones jack and there is no sound playing, I can hear a noise in the background. When I play a video, at the start, there is a sound like a crack or pop, and then the rest of the audio plays with no problem. But when I pause the video, another pop noise occurs, and the background noise starts again. Can someone help me? I do not think it is a hardware problem, because the sound works with no problem in Windows.
I try with a few solutions but none of them work.

- [Solution Attempt 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers)
- [Solution Attempt 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339625/lubuntu-ubuntu-13-audio-clicking-in-power-save-mode)
- [Solution Attempt 3](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2230750.html)
- [Solution Attempt 4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489722/laptop-speakers-make-noise-when-audio-jack-is-plugged-in)

Comment: Maybe try another Ubuntu flavor? For example Xubuntu 15.10 - you can install it in another partition, or simply try it from a live USB. Then you know if your existing Ubuntu is the culprit, which it seems to be, since Windows is OK in this matter. If another *buntu works, it might be a good idea to install that release from scratch.